# Converting xlsx to pdf using PHPExcel and download that pdf . work Fine on localhost

Tags: php, phpexcel

This code works fine on localhost but on live server it shows

> File Not Found

Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.

Here is my code

**excel.php**

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

$target = 'Myfile.xlsx';
include 'phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($target);

function datefix_excel($excel) {

    $dif=(41885-$excel)*86400;
    $seconds=1409737670-$dif;
    $date=date("d/m/Y",$seconds);
    return $date; }

//echo 'File ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' has been identified as an ',$inputFileType,' file<br />';

//echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory with the identified reader type<br />';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($target);

$i = 0;
$found = false;
try
{



    //
    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) 
    {

    //
    //$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    //now do whatever you want with the active sheet

    $worksheet->setShowGridLines(false);
    $worksheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A2_PAPER );
    $worksheet->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A2_PAPER );
    $worksheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToPage(true);
    $worksheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(1);
    $worksheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToHeight(0);

    $worksheet->getPageSetup()->setScale(40);
    $worksheet->getStyle('F1:F4')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(false);
    $worksheet->getStyle('D6:D8')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(false);


    $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
    $count = 0;
    $found == false;

    //

$worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
$highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
$highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
$nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
    for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
        $val = $cell->getValue();

            if($val==$_REQUEST['roll'])
            {
                //echo "Roll Number found: ".$_REQUEST['roll']." <br/>";
                $found = true;
               // $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C23',$val);
               $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C23',datefix_excel($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C23')->getValue()));

                $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
                $rendererLibrary = 'dompdf';
                $rendererLibraryPath = './' . $rendererLibrary;
                //require_once (realpath(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))."/libraries/pdf.php");
                //echo $rendererName.' and '.$rendererLibraryPath;
                if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName,$rendererLibraryPath)) {
                    die('NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .EOL .'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure');
                }
                header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                header("Pragma: public");
                header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                header("Cache-Control: private", false);
                header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="rename.pdf"'); //tell browser what's the file name
                header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
                $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
                $objWriter->setSheetIndex($i);
                //$objWriter->save('test.pdf');
                $objWriter->save('php://output');
                break;


            }
            else{
                continue;
            }


            }
        }

    //

}   
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    //echo $e;
}


?>
```

Comment: Don't convert it to pdf for every single cell in your loop.... surely you want a PDF of the entire worksheet or file rather than each individual cell

Answer (score 0):

I would check: 1) is current folder writeable? 2) pdf.php is commented out, try enabling it (why? local machine probably has PDF installed, server does not), 3) try saving to file instead of outputting to browser, this will bypass any browser / security issues.

Comment: Sir , How should i save it first .. ... Sir and it work finee on localhost ... but create a mess on live server ...

Comment: the file now asked for opening is corrupted or wrong formet .... its not opening ....